# QGIS 2.18.9 pluggin DXF2SHP

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, dxf, importerror

Again, Super new here.
I downloaded the DXF2SHP plugin, just to import the full characteristics of my files, but whenever I try to actually convert from a simple DXF file to SHP as I´m supposed to according to the instructions I keep receiving this back:
[image: Screenshot]

Any thoughts? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the plugin directly into QGIS. That is the easiest way.

[image]

If you make the download itself, you have to adjust the name of the directory.

`AnotherDXF2Shape-0.81` -> `AnotherDXF2Shape`

[image]

Comment: Worked! pluggin perfetly installed, however, still unable to import my text correctly.

Comment: can you upload the dxf File

Comment: Yes, this is one of them, is a  very simple file....Sharing the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pznlgs2hvkft9ve/AADzowOHtL_S1SkSOcR0GSkRa?dl=0

Comment: Where is the text problem? In QGIS I can see all. 
Do you have selected the EPSG code  correct?

Comment: I have selected the one on my time zone (EPSG 6367, UTM zone 12N), when imported and seen in google earth it is geographically correct, but there are number of texts that are not showing, please do explain if you mean something else, patience as it is my first week with this software.

Comment: I have attached the QGIS image above. Since everything should be correct. How to convert from QGIS Texts (Label) to Google Earth is a completely different topic for which you might ask a new question.

Comment: I was simply saying that the EPSG is correct by using an example, such as geo location (no different topic needed), I was not for some reason seeing the text as you do in the image attached, i do now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/) that I found it better than [DXF2SHP plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_dxf2shape_converter.html). I tested many times and it works very well.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, however. When I installed it was displayed as "no valid". it seems they are not compatible with my QGIS version 2.189, [image: Screen Shot 1]

There are several versions of the pluggin, but none of them seem to work on my installed QGIS version.[image: Screen Shot 2]

As I said , super new on this, not sure If I´m doing this the right way.

Comment: Download the plugin directly in QGIS.